# how can I use the object of a variable to represent a variable

Tags: r, variables, object

for example,

```
name <- c("CHLYT1","CHLYT2")

assign(name[1], 2)
assign(name[2], 4)

result <- name[1]
```

I want the `result` to be `2` ,not the `CHLYT1`

Comment: `result <- get(name[1])` - I don't know why you'd do this though.

Comment: this just an example, there are a lot of variables, I can not do this one by one

Comment: What you're doing here is madness, use a `list` - `mydata <- list(CHLYT1=2,CHLYT2=4)` or `setNames(list(2,4),name)` then `result <- mydata[[1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* achieve this by using

```
result <- get(name[1])
```

**But** it's very unconventional and a recipe for a lot of confusion.

---

There are several approaches to deal with this kind of situations. A super simple one would be to use a simple vector with *named elements*:

```
values <- c(CHLYT1 = 2, CHLYT2 = 4)
```

Then you can access those values with, obviously, their name:

```
result <- values["CHLYT1"]
```

or by their position

```
result <- values[1]
```

or even by the position of their name (corresponding to your approach)

```
result <- values[names(values)[1]]
```

In all situations, `result` will be equal to `2`.